# Shared database without using website?

Tags: database, desktop-application

I am trying to develop a system which stores the data that can be accessible by some people in different countries. However, I was thinking on a cost-free system. So, is there any way I can develop the system without using a web based solution? Please give me some advice.

Thanks a lot.
Regards

Comment: Can you elaborate? what exactly do you want to do?

Comment: @lal00 I was thinking on creating a desktop application using Netbeans IDE or Visual Studio which connected to MySQL. But then if different people in different places (i.e. different countries) want to access it, how can I do that? I know they can install the desktop application I created, but how can they access the database?

Comment: You can give them your ip address. Or you give your computer a hostname. In any case, a shared server with a MYSQL account will cost you 10 dollars or less.

Comment: By giving them my ip address, does it mean they have to be in the same network (accessing the same router) with me? Or it doesn't have to work that way? Im sorry i dont know much bout this as im not expert in networking. Thanks n regards.

Comment: You have to give them your internet facing ip address. Depending on your ISP this could change frequently.

Comment: Ahh, I see. But from what i have researched on the almighty internet, the IP address may change, am i right? Considering that the users who will use the system have zero knowledge about networking (they are just using the system), do you think it's better to make the database as a shared server (by using MYSQL account as you mentioned earlier)?

Answer (score 1):

> However, I was thinking on a cost-free system

Cost-free hosting doesn't exist.  You can self-host, but that costs:

- Electricity
- Internet setup/usage fees
- Domain setup/recurring fees (you could use DynDNS instead, but it costs time to set up and maintain)
- Hardware usage/maintenance/wear (eventual replacement)
- Software IT and maintenance.  You have to figure out how your server/database serving software works, how to secure it, and patch it regularly
- Opportunity cost on the time you take to set up the server software

If you have a shared database, it must be hosted somehow.

> Is there any way I can develop the system without using web based?

Many (most) databases already support networked access, so you can simply host the database.